# Getting Bundle Identifier for KEXT from .kext Directory Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, kernel, kernel-extension

I'm building a kernel extension and having a .kext directory for it.
From another library API, I'm using [KextManager APIs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/kextmanager.h?language=objc) to load this kext into kernel.

Everything looks fine, here is the code piece that I'm loading the kext with:

```
CFStringRef path = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, "awesome.kext", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, true);
OSReturn result  = KextManagerLoadKextWithURL(url, NULL);
```

It works great, however I need to know my bundle identifier to have control socket connection, and maybe unload the kext with `KextManagerUnloadKextWithIdentifier(kextId)` API later.

So I'm aware of `XXX.kext/Contents/Info.plist` which contains `CFBundleIdentifier` key with bundle identifier but I need some way of getting it programmatically (some API?) instead of reading `Info.plist` file and parsing it.

I also tried to replace `CFBundleIdentifier` string value with something else and load into kernel, it still works fine, so it looks like `Info.plist` is not reliable anyway.

Is there anything related? Any suggestions? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered 2 useful approaches recently, both based on [KextManagerCopyLoadedKextInfo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1562908-kextmanagercopyloadedkextinfo) API.

```
void handle_kext(const void* key, const void* value, void* context)
{
    // OSBundlePath - CFString (this is merely a hint stored in the kernel; the kext is not guaranteed to be at this path)
    CFStringRef bundle_path_key = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, "OSBundlePath", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    const char* bundle_id_cstring = CFStringGetCStringPtr(key, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    const char* bundle_path_cstring = CFStringGetCStringPtr(CFDictionaryGetValue(value, bundle_path_key, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    // #1 Approach: Compare your 'I-Want-This-BundleID' with loaded kext path
    // #2 Approach: Compare your 'I-Want-This-BundlePath' with loaded kext ID
}

void some_func()
{
    CFDictionaryRef loaded_kexts = KextManagerCopyLoadedKextInfo(NULL, NULL);
    CFDictionaryApplyFunction(loaded_kexts, handle_kext, NULL);
}
```